# Let $G=\langle x, y\mid x^7=y^3= e, yxy^{−1}=e\rangle$. Find $|G|$. Find a group that is isomorphic to $G$. Explicitly state the isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Let $G = \langle x, y \mid x^{7} = y^{3} = e, yxy^{−1} = e\rangle$. What is $|G|$? Find a familiar group that is isomorphic to $G$. Explicitly state the isomorphism.

I am trying to get a handle on understanding group presentations. At first glance, the group has at most 21 elements, however, I noticed: $$yxy^{−1} = e$$

implies that

$$yx = y \rightarrow yx = ye$$

Therefore, $x = e$ by the cancellation law. From my understanding, we're left with two possibilities, $|G| = 3$ or $|G| = 1$. The latter being the case that $y = e$ as well. I don't know how to narrow down answer.

If it is the case that $y = e$ then $y = y^{-1}$, but $y^{3} = e$ implies that $y^{2} = y^{-1}$...I thought that this would be enough to conclude that $|G| = 3$, but that last statement holds even when $y = e$.

Any guidance anyone can offer will be greatly appreciated. Is there a formal approach I'm completely missing to tackling questions like these?

Comment: That is a *presentation*, not a *representation*.

Comment: Yes, $|G|=3$. The subgroup $H$ of $S_3$ generated by $\bar{x} = \rm{Id}(S_3)$ and $\bar{y} = (1,2,3)$  has order $3$ and, $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{$x$ satisfy the relations of the presentation. This proves that $|G| \ge |H|$ and hence $|G|=3$.

Comment: But it is a very strange question, and I wonder whether the relation $yxy^{-1} = e$ is correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt So that's a formal way of determining the order? Find a group H with generators that satisfy the relation then it is the case that the presentation has the same order as the group?

Comment: @DerekHolt It was a past exam paper question, so it may be the case it's flawed. But what you see on my post is exactly what is written down on the paper.

Comment: @Malcolm in general given a presentation the group is assumed to be maximal so it would only be trivial if you were able to prove $y=e$ explicitly. Otherwise you should work under the assumption that the elements are free.

Comment: @CyclotomicField well that makes sense in a weird way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $yxy^{-1}=e$, we do indeed get

$$\begin{align}
x&=exe\\
&=(y^{-1}y)x(y^{-1}y)\\
&=y^{-1}(yxy^{-1})y\\
&=y^{-1}ey\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the relation $x^7=e$ becomes trivial, along with $yxy^{−1}=e$. We are left with

$$\begin{align}
G&\cong\langle y\mid y^3\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_3,
\end{align}$$

where the final isomorphism is given by

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: G&\to \Bbb Z_3,\\
x&\mapsto [0]_3,\\
y&\mapsto [1]_3,
\end{align}$$

where

$$[a]_3=\{ b\in\Bbb Z: 3\mid a-b\}.$$

The order of $G$ is clearly, then, three, since isomorphisms preserve order.